# How to run dot command with space in shell?

Tags: command-line, sqlite, jscript, wscript.shell

Using jScript to run a command line remotely. The first three commands work fine. It is not until i get to the dot command after I have opened the sqlite3 data base that it just stops executing. When I run .quit I either get 
sqlite> .quit
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
or ".import" is not recognized as an internal or external command.

```
try {
    // var ret = oShell.Run('cmd.exe cd c:\\sqlite', 1 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true /* bWaitOnReturn */);
    var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    // var ret = oShell.Run("cmd.exe /k @echo Hello", 1 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true/* bWaitOnReturn */);

    var ret = oShell.Run('cmd.exe /k cd c:\\sqlite && @echo ".import H:\\\\2019\\\\00028-000-19\\\\QPPData\\\\Directory_Proofs\\\\Index_007.txt test" && sqlite3 F:\\qpp.db; && ".import H:\\\\2019\\\\00028-000-19\\\\QPPData\\\\Directory_Proofs\\\\Index_007.txt test"', 1 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true/* bWaitOnReturn */);
    WScript.Echo("ret " + ret);

    //var ret = oShell.Run('cmd cd', 1 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true /* bWaitOnReturn */);
}
catch (err) {
    WScript.Echo(err);
}
```

Comment: So when I .quit the database this returns The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Is the only problem the directory path? If it is I have written it in and if I copy paste this it runs fine. So I am not sure if it is executing correctly and the path is wrong.

Comment: var ret = oShell.Run('cmd.exe /k cd c:\\sqlite && sqlite3 G:\\qpp.db; && sqlite3 qpp.db .show', 1 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true/* bWaitOnReturn */);

Comment: If I type .quit after this runs then it returns the sqlite show. So this command is returning after I type the quit command. So first I need to run sqlite commands using sqlite3. Then The next question is how do I get sqlite to return on it's own? Because you can't run any command lines while sqlite is running.